# How to check if TIdHTTP exception is raised

Tags: delphi, exception, delphi-2010, idhttp

I'm not sure if this is the best way to check if a TIdHTTP exception is raised, here is what I did:

```
HTTP := TIDHttp.Create(nil);
try
  try
    HTTP.Head(URL);
    SizeF := HTTP.Response.ContentLength;
    code := HTTP.ResponseCode;
  except
    on E: Exception do
    begin
      code := HTTP.ResponseCode;
      ShowMessage(IntToStr(code));
    end;
 end;
finally
  HTTP.Free;
end;
if code = 200 then
  // go download the file using multiple threads.
```

What I want to achieve is raising an axception is case there is one (I guess I already did) otherwise the program keeps running and download the file.
So is this the correct way to do it? Thanks for your replies.

Comment: Yes, you just use try/except to catch any exception in Head/Get/Post request. Note that download does not start because exception will interrupt the procedure - you can use Head and then Get in the same block.

Comment: This code swallows all exceptions, regardless of their type, and read the response code when it may be ill defined. I don't think this code does what you think.

Comment: It is supposed to work this way. He does not have to care much about the exception type if he needs only 1 result.

Answer (score 3):

As a common rule: Only handle exceptions when you can and want to handle them.

Otherwise let them just flow to stop the current execution of your code. Without any interception you will just receive a dialog with the exception message (this is handled by `TApplication`).

In this case you can change your code to

```
HTTP := TIDHttp.Create(nil);
try
  HTTP.Head(URL); 
  // if an exception is raised then the rest of the code will not be executed 
  // yes, the code in finally part will execute 
  SizeF := HTTP.Response.ContentLength;
  code := HTTP.ResponseCode;
finally
  HTTP.Free;
end;

// check if all conditions are met
if code <> 200 then
  // if not, raise a custom exception as you like
  raise Exception.Create( 'Not what I expected here' );

// go download the file using multiple threads.
```

Comment: If Head throws an exception (eg. code is 400 or 500), it will not reached that part "check if all conditions are met".

Comment: @smooty86 If Head throws an exception why would you try to Get the same url? The check all conditions is just an example for throwing a custom exception, not more

Comment: There are many reasons in the HTTP communication why he should retry. He should process the exception at that place and not out of scope.

Comment: @smooty86 Yes of course as I wrote in the answer: Handle only if you want and can. Sometimes you want to handle the (URL redirection)[https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/URL_redirection] (mostly the permanent ones). Then you have to react as you like. But if not, just set `HandleRedirect := true;` and do not care about.